# lwip_select blocks even after socket is closed

Tags: c, sockets, mqtt, freertos, lwip

In my current application, I am having an MQTT task, this MQTT task is woken up by another helper task whenever there is data available on the socket. I am currently achieving this by using lwip_select. So whenever there is an event, I use that to trigger a wakeup to MQTT task.

My helper task looks somewhat like this:

```
...
...
fd_set      read_fds;
fd_set      write_fds;
fd_set      err_fds;

FD_ZERO (&read_fds);
FD_ZERO (&write_fds);
FD_ZERO (&err_fds);

FD_SET  (s, &read_fds);
FD_SET  (s, &err_fds);

ctx->state = SST_RX_READY;
while( 1 )
{
    if (ctx->state == SST_RX_CLOSING)
    {
        ctx->state = SST_RX_CLOSED;
        vTaskDelete( NULL );
    }
    if( lwip_select( s + 1, &read_fds, &write_fds, &err_fds, NULL ) == -1 )
    {
        //if socket is closed lwip_select will return -1
        vTaskDelete( NULL );
        return;
    }

    if( FD_ISSET( s, &read_fds ) )
    {
        configASSERT( ctx->rx_callback );
        ctx->rx_callback( ( Socket_t )ctx );
        //vTaskDelay( 10 ); // delay a little bit to yield time for RX
    }
}
...
...
```

In the while loop I keep calling lwip_select and the timeout parameter is kept NULL on purpose because I do not want this task to time out at all, there could be long periods of time when there is no data to receive from MQTT. However if my main MQTT task finishes its job and gracefully closes the socket, this helper task is still active and is blocking on lwip_select.

Some extra info:
OS: Freertos 10.0.1
HW platform: Cortex m3
LWIP version: 2.4.0

Any possible leads to solve this will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you mean by "gracefully closes the socket"? You don't mean that you call some version of `close` do you? Do you have some case where a socket can be closed while it's still in use through a call to `lwip_select`? That's *definitely* not going to work. You can shut the connection down, but you must not close the socket while it's in use!

Comment: By "gracefully close socket" I mean the MQTT task will finish its job without error and call lwip_close. There is no case when the socket can be closed while its still in use, there are only 2 tasks that are active, the MQTT task and the helper task. MQTT task is responsible for opening, using and closing the socket. The helper task(snippet posted above) will only check if there are any packets to be received, if yes it will wake up MQTT task. However when MQTT task closes the socket and exits, the helper task is still blocking on lwip_select.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it so that the task blocked on `lwip_select` unblocks because you haven't done anything to make it unblock? Or are you asking why it doesn't unblock because you've done something to make it unblock? If the latter, what did you do to make it unblock? To be clear, the task in `lwip_select` is *not* selecting on the socket that you are closing, right? Because if so, you are closing the socket while it's still in use. Selecting on a socket is using that socket. (The generic answer for how one task can unblock another task in select is to send a dummy byte on a pipe.)